# Intellij DialogWrapper and Balloon notifications

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-plugin

I am writing an Intellij Plugin using Kotlin.

I have a class that extends DialogWrapper and that's where my GUI lives.

Problem:
How do I show a Balloon notification while the DialogWrapper is still visible? if this is not possible, how should I show the Balloon notification as soon as the DialogWrapper is dismissed?

So I want to trigger a Balloon notification when this function is invoked:

```
override fun doOKAction() {
    // Show Balloon Notification
    super.doOKAction()
}
```

Currently, when I trigger Balloon Notification I see my notification only in the Event Log.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Timer and schedule:

```
override fun doOKAction() {
    super.doOKAction()
    Timer("Show Balloon", false).schedule(500){
      // Show Balloon notification
    }
}
```